# Starter async class in Spring Framework 3

Tags: spring, asynchronous, apache-kafka, listener

how can i create a class in spring fw 3 that starts on deployment and runs asynchronously?

I need do a "while (true)" in this class to consume Kafka Topic but currently that loop don´t is async and dont finish, and war file dont finish the deploy.

Im trying with a "listener-class" and a "servlet" in web.xml.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Both listener-class and servlet sections are of the web specification and have nothing to do with spring. In particular they are not managed by spring, not bound to the Application Context lifecycle, there is no injection and so forth. They are basically managed and get called by web servlets container (like tomcat or jetty whatever you have in your setup)

In general, you need to learn about two concepts:

1. Listeners - these is something that gets called in different times of the application context loading (you need one that gets called when the application context is loaded right before it gets "ready") - all beans are created, injected, so you can start consuming kafka messages from there.

Technically the listener is a bean, so you can inject kafka definitions (I understand you don't use any spring kafka integration and define everything "manually")...

2. `@Async` Methods. In a nutshell, these are methods that spring can "off-load" to some thread pool so that they won't interfere with the main thread that starts the application context. If for some reason there is no support for async methods in your spring version- you can define a thread pool by yourself and "submit" a class that executes kafka polling in an endless loop.

So All-in-all you need a listener annotated with async + enable async support for your application.

A couple of links that might come handy:

[Async tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async)

[Listeners and events tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-events)

Comment: Thanks, but this is in Spring5 or Springboot. I need for Spring 3.